# Can CodeIgniter perform validation on individual forms that were dynamically created?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am writing a system where I have multiple inputs. If the first one doesn't pass the validation test, I want the next field to be saved if it does pass. However, at the moment, if the first one doesn't pass the validation test, everything fails and nothing is saved. So I thought of creating individual ones. I know that you can make individual groups in the config area. However, it seems that the rules/groups you make in the config for validation testing are predefined fields. They are never dynamically created.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write something customized. The whole idea of Validation is that it checks the validness of the whole set, and then, and only then, let the code pass.